# Running a different validation function depending on which range is met

Tags: c#, delegates

I need to run a different validation method say: Method1(int datum), Method2(int datum)...Method5(int datum) depending on which range this int belongs to.

My attempt at managing these ranges looks something like this right now (there are many of them, below is a simplification):

```
List<Tuple<int,int>> ranges = new List<Tuple<int,int>>()
{
   new Tuple<int,int>(10000,25000),
   new Tuple<int,int>(30000, 80000),
   new Tuple<int,int>(85000, 90000) 
}
```

How can I change this above structure so that I tie a specific method to each range, so that I can test the datum against the range and run the method associated with that range?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I don't understand your question, your wording doesn't match up to your example.  Are you trying to run a different method based on whether an int is within a specific range?  From your wording, you could accomplish it with multiple If statements...

Comment: What are the return types of your method?do all of them  have the same return type?

Comment: @Taegost you understood me correctly. Ideally, I didn't want to use if statements because in reality there are a lot of ranges and sometimes the same method may be used for several ranges.

Comment: @arash, yes they all return 'bool'

Comment: I know that I've already answered your question and you accepted my answer. BTW, the associated method has to test something? Or, could it be just a method with no return value (i.e. `void`)?

Comment: I wanted to test something, there is a somewhat complicated math operation inside of those methods.

Comment: @FailedUnitTest Ok! So it's fine then :)

Comment: @FailedUnitTest I've re-re-re-updated my answer. It's still the same approach, and based on your last comment, I feel that it should be closer to what you were looking for. Am I mistaken? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just about using delegates and a dictionary where keys are your ranges and values the methods:

```
public sealed class RangeOperationManager
{
    // A map of ranges to operations
    private Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Func<Tuple<int, int>, int, bool>> RangeToOperationMap { get; }
        = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Func<Tuple<int, int>, int, bool>>();

    // Encapsulates how to add new range to operation mappings. 
    // It's like a façade method.
    public void AddOperation(int min, int max, Func<Tuple<int, int>, int, bool> processor)
        => RangeToOperationMap[Tuple.Create(min, max)] = processor;

    public bool Operate(int input)
    {
        // We try to get an operation associated with a range based on the input
        var foundPair = RangeToOperationMap
            .SingleOrDefault
            (
                // Let's see if we find a range for the given input!
                pair => input >= pair.Key.Item1
                        && input <= pair.Key.Item2
            );

        // If this "if" evaluates true, it would mean that no range could be found
        //
        // NOTE: We need to check if retrieved pair isn't key-value pair default
        // value because it's an structure (value type).  
        if (!foundPair.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<Tuple<int, int>, Func<Tuple<int, int>, int, bool>>)))
        {
            // If some could be found, then we proceed to call the associated
            // delegate giving the range and input as arguments!
            return foundPair.Value(foundPair.Key, input);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Input couldn't match any of configured ranges");
        }
    }
}
```

...and for example, above `class` could be used as follows:

```
class Program
{
    // In some class who knows where...
    static bool Method1(Tuple<int, int> range, int input)
    {
        return true;
    }

    static bool Method2(Tuple<int, int> range, int input)
    {
        return true;
    }

    static bool Method3(Tuple<int, int> range, int input)
    {
        return true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RangeOperationManager rangeProcessor = new RangeOperationManager();
        rangeProcessor.AddOperation(10000, 25000, Method1);
        rangeProcessor.AddOperation(30000, 80000, Method2);
        rangeProcessor.AddOperation(85000, 90000, Method3);

        bool result1 = rangeProcessor.Operate(12300); // true
        bool result2 = rangeProcessor.Operate(35000); // true
        bool result3 = rangeProcessor.Operate(89000); // true
    }
}
```

### Further reading

In C# 7.0 there will be [syntactic sugar for tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)! I feel that I'll need to update my answer to use the wonders of syntax-integrated tuples in C# 7.0 and above.

Comment: That's a clever solution, Thanks!

Comment: Actually I was writing something like this code:) but yours is much nicer.perfect

Comment: @FailedUnitTest I've edited my answer, there were some issues, now I believe that it should compile ;) You're welcome

Comment: @arash Thanks for your comment! ;) BTW check my last update, there were some issues/errors, now it should work!

Comment: My apologies, but I think this solution is kind of difficult to read/understand.  And amount of comments prove it in some way. Then if one method need to validate few ranges? Does another key need to be add with same method? And what is purpose of using `Dictionary`? You not using it's benefits at all. I think collection will be more suitable, sorry I think  it is far from clever solution - just fast working solution... :)

Comment: @Fabio I've commented out the code because this is StackOverflow and the main purpose of answers is to be a good resource to improve our skills. Anyway, any experienced C# developer has already acquired LINQ and funcitonal skills, so the code speaks itself!

Comment: @Fabio About the solution being hard to understand... it's subjective.

Comment: @Fabio An answer doesn't need to be a GitHub repository of source code. I mean that obviously there should be issues with my approach, probably your concerns could be still solved with some modifications. In the other hand, **the benefit of using dictionary is that it's a *collection of key-value pairs*, which is almost what you're doing with classes in your answer...**.

Comment: @Fabio Yeah, I know it. BTW you don't need to worry about not being 100% aligned with a given answer. For me, it's not important what's the accepted answer, but that all answers provide a quality solution and all of them could provide different approaches to the same issue.

Comment: By commenting your question I didn't try to "raise" my answer. I am on "codereview" mood and your code was nice treasure for giving feedback :). Isn't StackOverflow for learning?

Comment: @Fabio Yeah, absolutely! That's why I'm discussing the code with you. I've re-updated the answer using the same approach but now it's enclosed within an actual class and its usage is even more clear!

Answer (score 1):

You can create class which takes collection of ranges and validation method as parameters, then loop all it instances until valid range found and execute validation method

```
public class Range
{
    public int Min { get; }
    public int Max { get; }

    public Range(int min, in max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }
}

public class ValidateRanges
{
    private readonly List<Range> _ranges;
    private readonly Func<int, bool> _validate;

    public ValidateRanges(List<Range> ranges, Func<int, bool> validate)
    {
        _ranges = ranges;
        _validate = validate;
    }

    bool IsInRange(int value)
    {
        return _ranges.Any(range => value > range.Min && value < range.Max);
    }

    public bool Validate(int value)
    {
       return validate(value);
    }
}
```

Then use in your code

```
var validateranges = new[]
{
    new ValidateRanges(new[] {new Range(0, 100),new Range(1000, 1100)}, ValidationMethod1),
    new ValidateRanges(new[] {new Range(101, 200)}, ValidationMethod2),
    new ValidateRanges(new[] {new Range(201, 500)}, ValidationMethod3),
};

foreach (var validation in validateranges.Where(val => val.IsInRange(value)))
{
    return validation.Validate(value);
}

return false; // default validation
```